# What is a change of circumstances that outweighs a previous overstay in a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, overstaying

I applied to the UK recently and I was refused on the grounds that I visited  my friend for more than the days I applied for. I applied to spend three weeks and ended up spending 141 days and did not explain in my recent application. However, my visa did not expire. They further stated that my subsequent applications are likely to be refused unless my circumstances change. So I want to find out how my circumstances can change.

Comment: Getting married with this friend might be a change they would think enough, but I would not get married because of it until you are sure you want to marry and you are sure it will be possible to live together afterwards.

Comment: Please show the complete refusal notice.

Comment: i dont have the letter on me now. i will post it tomorrow

Comment: Per the above comment, you can scan your refusal notice and upload it into your question. It should be two pages and you can use Paint to blacken out your name and GWF number. The question will most likely be closed until it's uploaded (or transcribed).

Comment: Please clarify about your previous visit. You say that you stayed longer than previous but "your visa did not expire". Can you clarify what visa you were previously awarded?

Comment: It might also be useful to know your nationality and where you applied from. (Although I don't think it would change much)

Comment: Your *visa* may not have expired, but what about the number of days your were given on your *entry stamp*? Be aware that the visa dates specify when you may arrive - they say nothing about when you must leave. The entry stamp in your passport is what you probably overstayed.

Comment: @brhans UK visas work differently to say US visas - you can't remain in the UK after expiry.

Comment: Yes that's true, but the date given by the immigration officer on the entry stamp may still have been different to the visa expiry date - and that is probably what went wrong in this case. The OP has only looked at the visa expiry date instead of the date given on her arrival.